# SQL Query to delete

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I'm trying to figure out how to write a MySQL query that will delete a person if they have a "X" in a column and is focused at the latest date (MsgDateTime) of all the entries for that person. So if their latest date is 09-03-13 and they have five previous entries and the 3rd has an X in the Flag column i would like to delete it. Thank you

This is my query so far:

```
IF @EventType <> 'A4H' 

DELETE FROM BFE.dbo.BFEDATA     
WHERE (Flag = 'X') and MsgDateTime  > NOW() ORDER BY MsgDateTime

END
```

I would enter in the table structure but i'm not sure how to.

Comment: Can you show a before/after of 1 sample of data in table form.  I'm having trouble following your text description.

Comment: whats the table structure look like?  you probably want to do something like  `DELETE FROM BFE.dbo.BFEDATA WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM BFE.dbo.BFEDATA     
WHERE person= 'THE PERSON' ORDER BY MsgDateTime DESC LIMIT 1) AND Flag = 'X' ;`

Comment: Joe T - Why not post this as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

what does the table structure look like?
You probably want to do something like
 
`DELETE FROM BFE.dbo.BFEDATA

 WHERE id IN

     (SELECT id FROM BFE.dbo.BFEDATA WHERE person= 'THE PERSON' ORDER BY MsgDateTime DESC LIMIT 1)

 AND Flag = 'X' ;`

Answer (score 0):

if you are using if block, can i assuming you are writing a procedure? if so then you can try this

in your declare block:

```
latest date;
```

then inside your if block:

```
select MsgDateTime into latest from BFE.dbo.BFEDATA 
where flag = 'x'
order by MsgDateTime desc
limit 1;

delete from BFE.dbo.BFEDATA where flag = 'x' and
MsgDateTime = latest;
```